# Once I create a change set can I update the files in change set?

Tags: rtc

I changed some files and created a new change set based on those changes. I did not deliver this change set. I have since updated the files that were contained in the original change set. These changes are appearing in 'Unresolved Changes' . Should it be possible to check in these changes to same change set ? 
When I try to move the files within 'Unresolved Changes' to an existing change set the change set is not appearing in drop down menu in Eclipse RTC client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should it be possible to check in these changes to same change set ?

Yes you can.

The contextual menu shows a

```
check in > new change set
check in > (an existing change set name)
```

Select the second entry, and you will add your modification to the *existing* change set.

The only case where this option is not available is when you *close* a change set (right-click / close).

Source: [help page](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_scm_eclipse_modify.html):

> Expand the Unresolved folder to see its contents.
>
> - To check in the entire set of unresolved changes to the current change set, right-click the `Unresolved` folder and click `Check-in all`.
> - To check in an individual item in the Unresolved folder, right-click it, click `Check-in`, and click `an existing change set` to receive the change, or click `New change set` to create a change set.
>     (A file or folder in a component cannot be part of more than one active change set.
>     When a file or folder is included in an active change set, all changes to it become part of that change set whether or not the change set is current, and changes to that file or folder cannot be explicitly checked in to a new change set until the active change set that includes it is completed.)

Comment: by 'close' do you mean 'complete' ? I have completed the change set so perhaps this is the reason I can no longer add files to it.

Comment: @user470184 if you see a little green tick on your change set, then yes, it has been completed, and you won't be able to add new files in it.